# Reuse started program instance in powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, visual-studio-code

Is there a possibility to reuse a started program instance elsewhere in a powershell script as in the following example:

```
$app
function startProgram(){
        ...   
        $app=& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code" $someArguments
}

function doSomethingWithProgram(){
        $app $someCLICommands
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .NET `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` classes:

```
$startInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$startInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
$startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($startInfo)
```

Then you can provide something as a `ProcessStartInfo` argument and start the process again:

```
$startInfo.Arguments = "C:\foo.txt"
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($startInfo)
```

[Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)
[ProcessStartInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)